# Is Falling applicable to Mouse Guard and similar classless games?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu, mouse-guard, classless, falling-system

I've got a strong inclination to purchase [Falling](https://maharhar.itch.io/falling) in preparation for running some classless games like Mouse Guard or Call of Cthulhu.

Are the steps inside largely applicable to a game like Mouse Guard? My reservations are that the sample image shows pairing by class, and I was worried it would beam hard to apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, it can apply to classless games

The primary, deeper exercise of answering multiple questions does not rely on class at all, and is intended for players or characters. The section involving classes is just a table suggesting a specific single question to use as a starting point for establishing character relationships. It does so by “type” rather than explicit classes.

The types are:

- Warrior/Melee Combat
- Priest
- Magic-User/ Ranged Support
- Magic-User/ Ranged Attack
- Rogue / Black Ops
- Specialist - Tinker/ Technologist
- Iconoclast
- All-Around / The Face

While these match up with the common fantasy archetypes or roles found in classes, they are not at all mechanically linked to those classes. The text refers to using these types as “preferred descriptors”, so for a classless game, match up your characters to the “types” that most closely match their personality and skills.

For *Mouse Guard* or *Call of Cthulhu* (or any game where fitting into those types might be a little harder), you could also imagine your investigators or mice playing the equivalent of *Dungeons & Dragons*, and choosing the character type they feel would suit them best. (This can be a fun character creation exercise all on its own, by the way, and often helps players who are used to class-based games.)

Alternatively, you could also select a question that seems appropriate, or roll for one randomly. The three spheres and their individual questions are numbered for this purpose.